# Javascript if/or comparison seems to spill into function call?

Tags: javascript

I'm absolutely stymied by this. On the line where I call "setCookie", if the second function parameter is the same (i.e. "art") as the current_cat OR comparison above it, that whole if statement breaks (and the function isn't called inside it). If I change the parameter so it doesn't match (i.e. "art_z"), then the code works. Problem happens with multiple "if" blocks; but the code works with just one "if" block. No amount of hacks could solve this - any ideas? Thanks so much in advance.

```
    var current_cat = getCookie("FOF_CURRENT_CATEGORY");

    if (menuitem == "menu_art" || current_cat == "art")  
    { 
    document.getElementById("menu_arc").className = "amble12graylight";
    document.getElementById("menu_art").className = "amble14blackregular";
    document.getElementById("menu_des").className = "amble12graylight";  
    document.getElementById("menu_fas").className = "amble12graylight";  
    document.getElementById("menu_sch").className = "amble12graylight";
    document.getElementById("menu_man").className = "amble12graylight";  
    setCookie("FOF_CURRENT_CATEGORY","art",365);
    }

    if (menuitem == "menu_arc" || current_cat == "arc")  
    { 
    document.getElementById("menu_arc").className = "amble14blackregular";
    document.getElementById("menu_art").className = "amble12graylight";
    document.getElementById("menu_des").className = "amble12graylight";  
    document.getElementById("menu_fas").className = "amble12graylight";  
    document.getElementById("menu_sch").className = "amble12graylight";
    document.getElementById("menu_man").className = "amble12graylight";  
    setCookie("FOF_CURRENT_CATEGORY","arc",365);
    }
```

Comment: While you are using two if's then what you want with the the both function? Should it enter into if condition or not?

Comment: The second if-block will execute if either `menuitem == "menu_arc"` or `current_cat == "arc"). This means that both if-blocks _can_ execute, overwriting each other's results.

Comment: Your description is a little confusing. Are you saying that your code breaks on setCookie("FOF_CURRENT_CATEGORY","art",365) but not on setCookie("FOF_CURRENT_CATEGORY","something_else",365)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem in the setCookie method.

Add a debugger and check what seems to be the problem there.

Or if you could share the code, which can be replicated, it would help.

Comment: Hi folks - another red, embarassed face here. Rups - I finally installed a debugger, and from Jan's comment found the problem, my statement should have read: `else if (menuitem == "menu_arc" || (menuitem == "" && current_cat == "arc"))` - Yes, I am ashamed. Thanks all.

Comment: It happens to all of us. :)